# How to handle "Cannot <METHOD> <ROUTE>" in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-4

As a minimal example, consider following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(errorhandler);

function errorhandler(err, req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Length', 0);
    res.status(500).end();
}

app.post('/example', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Length', 0);
    res.status(200).end();
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('server listening on http://%s:%s ...', server.address().address, server.address().port);
});
```

When I, for example, now try a `PUT` on `/example`, I get a `Cannot PUT /example` message with `404` status code. The same is true for all other routes and methods I did not declare. My error handler is only getting called on actual errors within a route or the body parser itself.

Is there a way to handle them by myself? I am using Express4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a general handler with no route after all other use/get/post/etc:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.status(404);
  res.render(...);
}
```

Comment: Works as expected. Thank you. Though, I am a bit confused by my error handler not handling this, even when placed last.

Comment: Nevermind, I found it: [express doc on error handling](http://expressjs.com/guide/error-handling.html) Clearly says 4 instead of 3 arguments for the error handling. Guess I missed that.